# Signed measure and it's decomposition

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two signed measures on $(X,\Sigma)$, so they have Unique Jordan decomposition as $\mu=\mu^+-\mu^-$ and $\nu=\nu^+-\nu^-$ where $\mu^+\perp \mu^-$ and $\nu^+\perp\nu^-$ (mutually singular). Total variation of any measure, for example $\nu$, is defined as $|\nu|=\nu^++\nu^-$. Can I prove $(\mu+\nu)^+=\mu^++\nu^+$? I like to extend the problem as below

Also, now considering $\nu$ is $\sigma $-finite signed/complex measure and $\mu $ is a $\sigma$-finite positive  measure on $(X,\Sigma)$, By the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem, $d\nu=d\lambda+fd\mu$ where $\lambda$ and $fd\mu$ are signed/complex measure. How do I prove 
$d|\nu|=d|\lambda|+|f|d\mu$ .Any hints regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\mu=-\nu$ seems to be a counterexample

Comment: At most an inequality holds.

Comment: Yes, you are right, $(\mu+\nu)^+ \le \mu^++\nu^+$. Thanks.